# Language.bin file have been found on my system after using Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

Recently, I have noticed a lot of language.bin files on my system after using Tor for a while.
The process I implement after closing Tor (or any other program, being VPN or direct connection) is to clean the system of any residual file. I have recently noticed the following files after closing Tor on my system:
Arabic.bin,
Czeck.bin,
Danish.bin,
Dutch.bin,
English.bin,
.
.
.
etc., (Total of 24 language.bin files).
I don't feel comfortable about this; specially since it is somthing that didn't happen previously. Is there somthing wrong going on? For what purpose the files being injected into my system? Does fingerprinting going on?

Comment: Are you talking about the Tor Browser Bundle? What OS are you running?

Comment: Yes Tor Browser Bundle.  Window XP

Comment: What folder are those bins stored in?

Comment: Local setting/Temp

Comment: Where did you download TBB originally? What version is it?

Comment: https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en

Comment: Version 3.5 - Windows 8, 7, Vista, and XP

Comment: Hello Dears; I had some free time and I decided to investigate this issue more deeply. I keep all previous versions of Tor Browser Bundle I have ever used for my reference. I decided to go through them one by one to figure out when this problem started to show up. It turns out that last version of Tor browser bundle that I used and did not show this problem was version 0.2.3-25-2 and the first version that this problem started to show was 0.2.3.25-4 and the problem continues up to current vesion 3.5. By the way I have no record of version 0.2.3.25-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those *.bin files do not belong to the Tor Browser Bundle (TBB). I downloaded the latest version of TBB and the only two files which had `bin` in their names were:

- `bing.xml`
- `toolbar_button_binding.xml`

Those *.bin files seem to come from some sort of audio driver (maybe Realtek audio). The poster in this [thread](http://forum.piriform.com/?showtopic=23229) recommends to disable the onboard audio. The thread also has some more recommendations. However the *.bin files are surely not Tor related.

Answer (score 1):

The bin files in the Temp folder are generated by RtHDCpl.exe from Realtek.

1. Print msconfig in the run command.
2. select the start page and remove the mark at RtHCCpl